# How to develop combobox in window phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, combobox, controls

How to develop combobox in window phone 7 ? How to change the color of combobox when click on it?

Answer (score 5):

The ListPicker is generally more optimized for WP7 touch interface than the default ComboBox. I'd stick with it if possible.

Comment: To clarify for @monika, the `ListPicker` control is part of the [Silverlight Toolkit for Windows Phone](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/), which is avialable via Codeplex or [NuGet](http://www.nuget.org).

Answer (score 0):

By default, it is not in the toolbox. But you can still use it. [Here is an article](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/metro-style-combobox-windows) that introduces you both to the basics of `ComboBox` and shows how to style it so it looks more Metro-like.

Comment: Don't use this! It's  bad bad bad! Use the ListPicker control from the Silverlight Toolkit instead! http://silverlight.codeplex.com/

Comment: Not really. For small projects with small datasets, there is no problem using the default control.

Comment: Except what you're talking about is NOT a default control. It's a imported Silverlight control, and there's NOTHING like it used anywhere else on the phone. So no, it's **ALWAYS** wrong to use that. If you want to write shitty UX apps, I suggest you go write stuff for Android.

Comment: That's why the article above shows how to style it to be ready for Metro. It all depends on specific cases and it is plain wrong to generalize the control usage to "do not use because it's not a part of the foundation" - it does the job at a pretty decent level.

Comment: Why go to the effort of making the non-standard ComboBox control more "Metro-like" when the ListPicker control is platform-specific, provides the same (and more functionality) and is already "Metro-like".

Comment: Dennis: It's still not "metro like" considering it's still a combobox! You seem to have no clue on how the other listselectors looks on the platform. There's either the inline version, that expands and shows a few items directly on the screen (like dark/light theme), or the full screen selector (like date/time picker for the Calendar or Alarm)

Comment: Again - I am talking about "it is possible to do it." Every control is targeting specific usage cases, and for some - ComboBox might be more suitable than ListPicker. Consider this as "general information."

Comment: No, ComboBox will never be more suitable. You doesn't even know what the ListPicker control looks like! -- See pictures.

Comment: @Dennis - But the SL Toolkit's ListPicker does a better job of the same functionality and matches the behavior that the native apps use. Example: Selecting a theme and accent colour in settings

Comment: I've used the SL toolkit in several cases and I am well aware of what it offers. WP Settings dialog anyone? Consider a styled ComboBox as another way to show user information in addition to ListPicker.

Comment: @Dennis - I think you misunderstand. The ComboBox is not available in the toolbox or styled because the SDK team does not intend for you to use it _ever_.

Comment: No, since a ComboBox still uses a Popup. Which have nothing to do with platforms UX.

Comment: @Richard - I already mentioned it - I am not saying "use only ComboBox." The point is - it is possible to if one wants to. Claus - I have no problems with custom invoked Popup elements.